# Can't Enter(type) a PIN at chrome remote desktop

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, remote-desktop

I want to use chrome remote desktop and installed.
but I can't enter PIN in its form.

I try paste letter that type in Notepad　bad failed .

please give me advise.

(windows10)

[image: page image]

It only accepted numbers. Solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem.
Because it's a PIN, only numbers can be entered.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

GO TO THE REMOTE DESKTOP CLIENT ON YOUR DESKTOP AND CHANGE THE PIN TO YOUR OWN PIN WITHOUT LETTERS THEN ENTER YOUR NEW PIN ON DESKTOP REMOTE PHONE APP

Comment: Pleas use correct case: Don't shout at people!